# Tkinter indeterminate progress bar not running as expected

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a simple gui.
I am taking url from the user in the Entry. When the button is pressed, url is saved in a file and another function is called to start another process through call (within subprocess).
while the process runs, I want to show the indeterminate progress bar (until the button is hit the bar needs to be hidden) and when the process is completed a showinfo message displays to destroy the gui.

Problem: The bar doesn't show up until the process is finished. After the showinfo dialog is displayed, only then it starts progressing. Means, the bar starts progressing the moment it should actually get destroyed.
What is wrong with my code?

```
import scrapy
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as tkms
from tkinter import ttk
import shlex
from subprocess import call
    

def get_url():
    # get value from entry and write to a file


def scrape():
    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
    progress_bar.grid(row=3, column=2)
    progress_bar.start(10)

    command_line = shlex.split('scrapy runspider /media/mayank/Local/Coding/Lab/Scraping/Practices/img.py')
    call(command_line)
    
    mes = tkms.showinfo(title='progress', message='Scraping Done')
    if mes == 'ok':
        root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")

 
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=90, textvariable=url)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Process", command=lambda: [get_url(), scrape()])
my_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

----Updated Code ---

```
import scrapy
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox as tkms
    from tkinter import ttk
    import shlex
    from subprocess import call
        
    
def get_url():
        # get value from entry and write to a file

scrapy = None


def watch():
    global scrapy
    if scrapy:
        if scrapy.poll() != None:
            # Update your progressbar to finished.
            progress_bar.stop()
            progress_bar.destroy()
            # Maybe report scrapy.returncode?
            print(f'scrapy return code =--######==== {scrapy.returncode}')
            scrapy = None
        else:
            # indicate that process is running.
            progress_bar.start(10)
            print(f'scrapy return code =--######==== {scrapy.returncode}')
            # Re-schedule `watch` to be called again after 0.1 s.
            root.after(100, watch)


def scrape():
    global scrapy
    command_line = shlex.split('scrapy runspider ./img.py')
    scrapy = Popen(command_line)

    watch()

    mes = tkms.showinfo(title='progress', message='Scraping Done')
    if mes == 'ok':
        root.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")

url = tk.StringVar(root)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=90, textvariable=url)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Process", command=lambda: [get_url(), scrape()])
my_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
progress_bar.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `subprocess.call` *interrupts* the current process until the called process is finised.
So the GUI won't update until the call is finished.

**Important takeaway:** *Never call `subprocess.run`, `subprocess.call` or one of the other convenience functions from the main thread of a `tkinter` program. Doing so will freeze the GUI. You should only create `subprocess.Popen` objects from the main thread.*

What you should do instead is create a `Popen` object, while at the same time disabling the start button.

To track the progress, define a function that is periodically called with `root.after()`, say every 0.1 s.
In this function you could call the `poll()` method to check if the subprocess has finished.
Alternatively, you could set `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and read the data from the subprocess from the `stdout` attribute of the `Popen` object.

The code below is a *working* (for me) example based on your updated question.
Note that I have replaced `scrapy` (which I don't have) with a relative long-running command on my UNIX machine.
Since you are running scrapy as a subprocess, you should not need `import scrapy`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as tkms
from tkinter import ttk
from subprocess import Popen


proc = None


def watch():
    global proc
    if proc:
        if proc.poll() is not None:
            # Update your progressbar to finished.
            progress_bar.stop()
            progress_bar.destroy()
            # Maybe report proc.returncode?
            print(f'proc return code =--######==== {proc.returncode}')
            proc = None
            mes = tkms.showinfo(title='progress', message='Scraping Done')
            if mes == 'ok':
                root.destroy()
        else:
            # indicate that process is running.
            progress_bar.start(10)
            # print(f'proc return code =--######==== {proc.returncode}')
            # Re-schedule `watch` to be called again after 0.1 s.
            root.after(100, watch)


def scrape():
    global proc
    command_line = ['netstat']
    proc = Popen(command_line)

    watch()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")

url = tk.StringVar(root)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=90, textvariable=url)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Process", command=lambda: [get_url(), scrape()])
my_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
progress_bar.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Popen without wait executes the function but simultaneously executes the next line as well which I don't want. So I used call (which implicitly uses Popen.wait) and the progressbar is stucked. So what should I use, multiprocessing? or something you can suggest?

Comment: @MayankMishra See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. I have updated the code in the question as per your code but I am getting the same result as Popen (without wait). Process runs but simultaneously the next line is executed in scrape and message box is shown. I have taken the creation of progressbar outside scrape function and inteh watch function starting and stopping the progressbar. The next line of code should not get executed until the process stops. Please see if I have done some mistake.

Comment: The message box should be called from `watch`, not `scrape`. I've updated my answer to one that works for me on a UNIX machine by running a different process. You should probably change that back to scapy.

Comment: thanks. The suggestions you have given regarding root.after, poll, and returncode have not only added my knowledge but also with a little tweak now the code is running as expected. Really thanks a lot. I don't have enough repo to upvote (though did try).

Comment: thanks for the updated code and many thanks for your great help. Marked as answer.

Comment: Can you please have a look to my another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653490/using-multiprocessing-in-tkinter-progressbar-not-running-as-expected). Due to some problems in gui, instead of Popen I am using multiprocessing. And to start/stop the progressbar I used the `if` on `process.is_alive` just like in the above code. But it seems process freezes execution of next line and `process.is_alive` always remain true even after job is done.